# Creating String Array joining elements of 2 arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

Here are my Inputs :

```
$firstname=array
("Raj","Swati","Kunal","Hema","Kareena","Deepika","Shilpa","Amitabh","Shahrukh","Kangana");

$lastname=array
("Kumar","Sharma","Kapoor","Malini","Kapoor","Padukone","Shetty","Amitabh","Shahrukh","Kangana");
```

I need to create an array that will concatenate $firstname[i] with $lastname[$i}and thereby create an array that combines the first name and last name.

My output is below but it is not correct:

```
<?php
foreach($firstname as $first){
   foreach($lastname as $last){
  $fullname[]=$first." ".$last;
  }
}
print_r($fullname);
?>
```

I probably should not be using a foreach loop but I am stuck.

Comment: You need to use a loop; but not two loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming arrays of the same size:

```
$firstname=array("Raj","Swati","Kunal","Hema","Kareena","Deepika","Shilpa","Amitabh","Shahrukh","Kangana");    
$lastname=array("Kumar","Sharma","Kapoor","Malini","Kapoor","Padukone","Shetty","Amitabh","Shahrukh","Kangana");
$size = count($firstname);
for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $fullname[]=$firstname[$i]." ".$lastname[$i];
}
```

Comment: plain and simple. Love it !

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(Here I just loop through both arrays with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and return them both concatenated into the `$result` array)

```
<?php

    $firstname = ["Raj", "Swati", "Kunal", "Hema", "Kareena", "Deepika", "Shilpa", "Amitabh", "Shahrukh", "Kangana"];
    $lastname = ["Kumar", "Sharma", "Kapoor", "Malini", "Kapoor", "Padukone", "Shetty", "Amitabh", "Shahrukh", "Kangana"];

    $result = array_map(function($v1, $v2){
        return "$v1 $v2";
    }, $firstname, $lastname);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Raj Kumar [1] => Swati Sharma [2] => Kunal Kapoor [3] => Hema Malini [4] => Kareena Kapoor [5] => Deepika Padukone [6] => Shilpa Shetty [7] => Amitabh Amitabh [8] => Shahrukh Shahrukh [9] => Kangana Kangana )
```

Comment: is this an anonymous function youve used ?

Comment: @newbie Yes! The advantage with this method is when lets say you have 1 element more in `$lastname` your results array will just end with e.g. `[x] => lastname` so you don't have to worry if they are the same length

Answer (score 0):

Provided you know the data in both arrays is in the correct order:

```
$out=[];
foreach($firstname as $key=>$val)
    $out[$key] = $val . ' ' . $lastname[$key];

var_dump($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `array_combine`;

```
$newArr = array_combine($firstname, $lastname);

foreach($newArr as $key => $value){
  echo $key." ".$value;
}
```